# Prove $\sqrt{2}$ is between $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{a+2b}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Show that $\sqrt{2}$ always lies between $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and $\dfrac{a+2b}{a+b}$.

Please give the easy solution as possible.

Comment: @Cure: "Obviously"? If you see a counterexample, it would be helpful to show it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Denote $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{a+2b}{a+b}=\frac{x+2}{x+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+x}$.
If $x< \sqrt{2}$ ($x$ cannot be $\sqrt{2}$ because $x$ is a rational), then $1+x< \sqrt{2}+1$, $\frac{1}{1+x}> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}=\sqrt{2}-1$. Thus $y> \sqrt{2}$.

The other case can be proved similarly.

Comment: Nice. Very clean.